# How do i specify the root path to my dropbox folder with python API call

Tags: python, api, directory, dropbox

I am trying to write a basic API to read files in my root dropbox folder by passing an empty string to represent the root. However it returns a Validation Error:

```
 ValidationError("'%s' did not match pattern '%s'"
stone.backends.python_rsrc.stone_validators.ValidationError: 'test.txt' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

My call is:

```
# Path to the Dropbox folder you want to read files from
FOLDER_PATH = ""

def read_files_from_folder():
    # Create a Dropbox client
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN)

try:
    # Get the list of files in the specified folder
    files = dbx.files_list_folder(FOLDER_PATH).entries

    for file in files:
        # Get the file metadata
        metadata = dbx.files_get_metadata(file.path_display)

        # Check if the file is a file (not a folder)
        if isinstance(metadata, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            # Get the file contents
            file_path = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, metadata.name)
            _, res = dbx.files_download(file_path)
            file_contents = res.content

            # Process the file contents as needed
            print(f"File Name: {metadata.name}")
            print(f"File Contents:\n{file_contents}\n{'=' * 50}")

except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Call the function to read files from the Dropbox folder
read_files_from_folder()
```

Answer (score 0):

To start listing the contents of the root, you would use the empty string `""` as the `path` when calling [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder), as you do in this code.

Looking at the error you shared though, you're actually supplying a `path` of `'test.txt'`, not an empty string, for the call that's failing.

Comparing that with your code, it looks like it's actually the `dbx.files_download(file_path)` call that's failing and producing that error, since you're doing `file_path = os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, metadata.name)`. Non-root paths like that should start with a "/".

So, for that `files_download` call, you would instead do: `dbx.files_download(metadata.path_lower)`

Also, `files_list_folder` and [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) return the same [`Metadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.Metadata) objects as `files_get_metadata`, so you don't need that [`files_get_metadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_get_metadata) call for each file. You can skip the `files_get_metadata` call and do the `files_download` call like: `dbx.files_download(file.path_lower)`

Comment: excellent thanks for your help! Managed to get it working from that feedback